# The window of web app which is builded by phonegap in ios7 is larger than normal

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

My phone gap app is strange in iOS 7.Its window size is larger than normal.The normal is 320*640.The real is 768*1152.

```
console.log($(window).width());//768
console.log($(window).height());//1152
```

So,this situation causes some of my app is not display.I want to know why ,and how to solve this?

I print the width and height of the main screen.

```
NSLog(@"width = %f",[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width);//320
NSLog(@"height = %f",[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height);//640
```

It seems that this guy gets the same trouble with me.[Here](https://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4424).

The follow is mine.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

If I remove width=device-width,my app looks normally.But I always think that this is not the solution forever.

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode project,I set the device model is iPhone,not universal.So run my app in iPad,this situation come with ios7,just in the ios7 iPad.
If I set the device model is universal,the app is normal.But I still don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why too. This only occur for iPhone Only App when run in iPad iOS7.

But try check your html ViewPort meta tag and remove "width=device-width" and "height=device-height" properties.

Hope this help...

Comment: After I set the meta tag,the same with u ,the problem has still existed.But thank u.